# Guava conflict with Jboss 8 (Wildfly) and Java 8

Tags: java, jboss, guava, wildfly

I'm migrating my applications from Java 7 on JBoss 7.1, to Java 8 and Wildfly (Jboss 8.1).

When I tried starting Wildfly I got an error, the server was up but my app wasn't loaded. Looking on the Caused By I can see a more descriptive problem:

> Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Set with
>   qualifiers @Default   at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter]
>   Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager(Set)   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager.(ServiceManager.java:0)

This `ServiceManager` class belongs to Google Guava. I have tried Guava 17, 16 and 15 and the problem still persists.

**Update:** I updated the question to give more details thanks to ColinD answer.

In my pom.xml I have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>17.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and the error is related to Guava 15. I took a look at my deployed application directory and saw that my lib directory contains two guava jars: `guava-17.0.jar` and `guava-15.0-cdi1.0.jar`.

I removed this strange guava-15.0-cdi1.0 jar file and my server started although my app didn't load. I think this is related to Wildfly dependencies and CDI.

Does anybody know how to resolve this conflict on Wildfly?

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1433

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ServiceManager` hasn't had `@Inject` or `@Singleton` on it since Guava 16.0. One way or another, it looks like you have a version of Guava <= 15.0 on your classpath.

Comment: +1. Thanks to point that. I've updated my question to give more details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this Sounds like you are packaging guava 15 or so. It definately works with guava 16. I know this because I had the Same problem. I was able to resolute it by packaging a later guava Version with my ears.
May it be that you are declaring a dependency to the guava module of wildfly instead of just packaging a guava lib with your deployment?